# Subscribing Children class from observable has no parent fields

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, rxjs, observable

I have observable that gets some data from server. This data is stored just in public fields of DocGroup object.

```
export class DocGroup extends Selectable {
  public uuid;
  public name;
  public set_uuid;
  public order;
  public strings;
}
```

I need this object to have some extra functionality so it extends class called Selectable, which allows my object to be selected for further processing.

```
export class Selectable {

  public readonly isSelectable = true;
  public selection_parent: Selectable;
  protected _selected: number = -1;

  public select(state?: boolean) {
    // Some body
  }

  // And so on 
}
```

**The problem** is that this object has no parent fields and methods when parsed with JSON despite it's type is said. When i try to call it's select() method i get exception *"group.select is not a function"*. Object is loaded like this:

```
public getAll(contract: Contract): Observable<DocGroup[]> {
  const url = this.baseUrl + 'getAll';
  const response: Observable<DocGroup[]> = this.http.post<DocGroup[]>(url,
    {"contract_uuid": contract.uuid}, this.httpOptions);
  return response;
}
```

Also after i printed object to console i found out that it has no parent fields too:

```
{
  "uuid":"3fe5329a-888c-4a59-e99b-aa5b8c5791dc",
  "set_uuid":"6c8d33c3-c147-4d36-db0d-e41f7d9b87b3",
  "order": null,
  "name":"Group 1"
}
```

So how can i get my object via HTTP having all methods and fields in place? Maybe Selectable could somehow be an interface and i'm breaking some design patterns so that's why this problem occurs?

I've already tried to adjust my object with Object.assign(), but it only added missing fields, not methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http operations *shape* the data as the defined interface. They do not create *instances* of the defined type. So the fields are *not* checked against the class structure (and if you send something extra or wrong, it will just append it.)

To work with the returned data as instances, you need to create them yourself from the provided "shaped" data.

Here is an example:

```
  // Mapping to a class instance
  this.http.get<ProductClass[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Before map', JSON.stringify(data))),
      map(products => products.map(product => {
        const productInstance: ProductClass = Object.assign(new ProductClass(), {
          ...product,
          price: product.price * 1.5,
          searchKey: [product.category]
        });
        productInstance.inventoryValuation = productInstance.calculateValuation();
        return productInstance;
      })),
      tap(data => console.log('After map', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

The above code uses a `map` RxJS operator to map the products array. Then uses the array map to iterate through each product.

The first line within the map operator creates the class instance using Object.assign. In Object.assign, we start with a new instance of the class using the `new` keyword. Then we copy the product in using the spread operator (...). This is the code that gives us an actual instance.

```
Object.assign(new ProductClass(), { ...product } )
```

The price and searchKey fields are added as needed for this specific example. You may not need to add fields to your resulting object.

I then use the instance to call a method (`calculateValuation`), primarily to demonstrate that we now have an instance and can call methods on it.

For your code, it would look more like this:

```
Object.assign(new DocGroup(), { ...item} )
```

Comment: This spread operator use is pretty clever, that's thing i was looking for but was not aware of :)

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as such to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize and de-serialize data via JSON (or any other data exchange format), all type or class information will be lost.

There is no builtin typescript feature to automatically create a class object from the plain javascript object.

There are some 3rd party modules for this. I recommend using class-transformer (https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer).

Comment: But what defining data type with TS gives me then? Doesn't it check that data i got came in right format and has all fields required?